# OS X - How do you stop a bash script from running on startup?

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, jruby

I recently downloaded [Ruby Switcher](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2009/07/29/ruby-switcher-working-with-multiple-ruby-versions-has-never-been-this-easy) in an attempt to switch back to Ruby from JRuby. I eventually switched back to normal Ruby by other means so I deleted `ruby_switcher.rb` as it was of no further use to me. Now, at every startup I get this very annoying message in my terminal:

```
-bash: /Users/ethanwilkins/ruby_switcher.sh: No such file or directory
```

How can I stop this message from appearing without restoring the file?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably getting called in your profile file.

Usually, the file is `.bash_profile` and is located in your home dir.

Answer (score 1):

After reading what bash says about startup files, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.